# Is it a good practice to write methods that return void?

Tags: java, return, return-value, void

I am working on a complex enterprise application coded in java that is driven by complex object compositions. For example : In a particular scenario, to perform an action this is the flow:

```
login() -> 
Followed by defined sequence of 10 to 20 method calls in different classes -> 
Followed by a logout()
```

Within the framework, almost all the actions including the login, logout, and many of the 10 to 20 method calls have no return types. Any erroneous behavior is handled by the framework. Say, in login

```
public void login(){
try{
 //login actions
 //chained sequence of calls

}catch(){
 // framework handling exceptions and other rollback options
}
}
```

The intermediate 10 to 20 actions are method calls on different objects at different levels of hierarchy of the framework.

A random class would look like this :

```
class someobject{

def variable

void action1(){ do something on variable }
void action2(){ do something on variable }
...
}
```

The variable changes state often and these actions have a sequence defined only by the framework which I find very annoying.

I'd say, Probably if there were appropriate return types at all or at least some of these methods, as in say boolean in the case of `login()`, life would be a lot easier. Because of this tight adherence to a series of void returning functions, I find it difficult to debug through to understand the flow and also unit testing became a nightmare to me.

So now, I am under the impression that it is always better to write functions that return something, *especially when there is a chain of actions involved*. So, Is this a safe presumption? I'd want to take your opinions on this. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What you explain here sounds like that you're missing a proper component driven design. The approach will result in unmaintainable 'spagetti code'. You may need to introduce some intermediate layers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most basis testability of a method is via its return code.  In the case of `login` you need (as you noted) to be able to test whether you are now logged in, and a `boolean` return is the obvious way.  Otherwise you have to check some property, which seems unnecessarily non-atomic and complex (though might be needed for other reasons).

To me, this argument extends to any meaningful method.  Using `void` return codes is pretty common but more as a result of old habits than for good design reasons.  Simple property setters are a counter-example though, and I am sure there are others.

Comment: If you're a fan of functional programming (which I am), I'd go a step further and say void methods are a sign of mutable state - which is bad.

Answer (score 2):

When a method operates on local data in the class, a void method is perfectly reasonable, as long as it models some "behaviour" that makes sense in the context of the class.  For example, if you have a SpecialSortedList that sorts its contents, i.e. myList.sort(), the sort() method would be void as it models some behaviour associated with a SpecialSortedList.

If a method does not operate on local data within a class, i.e. it accepts its data through parameters and returns some piece of data (i.e. no reliance on local data), it is good practice to declare it as static and even move it to a utility or helper class.

Comment: Are you saying, that methods like "Add" "Remove" or "Update" in Data Repository or any other Data Provider should return something? Bool ? or id of just created record?

Comment: In my opinion, the sort method you talk about should return the sorted list, and not do scary things with side effects, then return void.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion its not necessary to always return something on chain of actions It totally depends on your requirements. I.e in login Authentication method its better to return Boolean result for simplification. If chain of actions are independent of one and other then In my opinion there's no need to return anything which will not be used by any action. So if the result of one action effect the next action then it should return something for simplification and testing so you can tract directly from the output of the method which is causing issues. Once method is identified then you can check the specific method which is identified. So basically every thing is depends on your requirements. If your requirements are better handled without returning something then you should go with it. Also you should follow the best practices or design patterns for effectiveness which will be more better for all situations and you can get rid of creating mess at the end.  Its just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

More and more, I prefer to return something like a status code instead of void.  This does a couple of things:

1. I allows the code the called your function to know what to do next (for example, if the operation failed then the calling code may need to do something different that if the operation succeeded).
2. It is easier to test and debug (as you mention).  I have begun to believe that writing code for testability is one of the best ways to ensure code quality (assuming of course that you do actually test it).  Void functions are hard to test.

My preference is to, whenever possible, have most functions take paramters, return an answer and not change any class variables.  As Jaco mentioned, these can be declared static and even moved to a utility class.  Then you can have a few controller functions make use of the functions that do return values.

Answer (score -2):

I would split the answer as 2 parts:

- When is returning "void" useful -

  **If the method is returning a value only to indicate an incorrect state/exception, then it should be returning "void". The Exception should take care of handling all the error scenarios rather than a say a "boolean" return value**.  Now, the calling code needs to again validate both the boolean and the exception. If it had thrown only Exception, then it is much easier & clearer for the calling code.
- When is returning void not so useful -

  If the method performs any operation and returns a value as a result, then "void" should not be  returned, the relevant result type(boolean/integer/object etc.) needs to be returned.

**In general, return value should actual correspond to whether the method returns something or not. It should not correspond to whether the method executed right (well, it is supposed to).** All the input validation/exception scenarios should be handled by means of throwing corresponding exceptions. Example, throw IllegalArgumentException when input is invalid, rather than returning "boolean" saying method did not execute.

Comment: I completely disagree that exceptions should be used as the focal point to communicate regular failure scenarios.